# Find $f, g$ such that $f'=g, g'=f, f(0)=1, g(0)=0.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am struggling with

If $f, g$ satisfy $f'=g, g'=f, f(0)=1, g(0)=0$,
find $[f(10)+g(10)]\cdot [f(10)-g(10)]$.

And the following flash across my mind.[image]

So, I guess the answer of  $[f(10)+g(10)]\cdot [f(10)-g(10)]$ is $1$.

Could you please solve or prove this. Really thank you.

Comment: What? Please make your post more legible.

Comment: You have a good future ahead of you.  That was a good thought.  But clearly $f (x)=g (x)=e^x $ is a solution.  can you combine those reasults.

Comment: You don't actually have to solve fo f and g I think.  Just express those in terms of derivatives and... something will probably happen.

Comment: Oh... wait ... f=g=e^x obvious don't satisfies f (0)!=g (0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want $f^2-g^2$. Differentiating that, gives $2ff’-2gg’=0$ by the given conditions, so $f^2-g^2$ is a constant. Plug in $x=0$ to get the constant.

Comment: Shortest possible answer. Does exactly what is needed and nothing more. +1

Comment: MARVELOUS... wow...

Answer (score 2):

Congrats, you've just solved a simple dynamical system:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 \\
    0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x'\\
    y'\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    y\\
    x\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with initial condition:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x(0)\\
    y(0)\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The above has general solution:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x(t)\\
    y(t)\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}c_1e^{-t}(e^{2t}+1) + \frac{1}{2}c_2e^{-t}(e^{2t}-1)\\
    \frac{1}{2}c_1e^{-t}(e^{2t}-1) + \frac{1}{2}c_2e^{-t}(e^{2t}+1)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

using the initial conditions, we get the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    c_1\\
    c_2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore the particular solution is:

$$x(t) = \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2},$$ $$y(t) = \frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2}$$

This solution is unique since the matrix mapping is continuous.

Note that you can also look at the system as a standard second order ODE with:

$$x(t) = x''(t)$$

and initial conditions:
$$x(0) = 1$$
$$x'(0) = 0$$

particular solution is:

$$x(t) = \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2}$$

$x'(t)$ follows via differentiation.

For more info, check out:

1. https://www.ru.ac.za/media/rhodesuniversity/content/mathematics/documents/thirdyear/linearcontrol/AM32LC2%20Linear%20Dynamic%20Sys.pdf
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system

Comment: Wait a sec.. Is it differential equation, isn't it? .  But I met this PROBLEM in high school math...

Comment: Yup... system of coupled ode's. Check out some refs. If you know a little linear algebra, you can grok it!

Comment: Also, just because something arose in high school math, doesn't mean it doesn't have deeper implications — watch out for that and keep asking why!